# How to calculate RMSD with GLIDE?

Tags: docking, geometry, schrodinger-software, software-assistance

I need to calculate the RMSD between a co-crystallized ligand and my ligands and a non-co-crystallized ligand with GLIDE but I don't know how. Could someone explain to me how to do it? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is using Glide necessary in your project? So many softwares can calculate RMSD, I name a few of them: VMD, GROMACS, MDanalysis, Chimera...

Comment: +1. Hopefully you get an answer quickly. Maybe one of the programs that Y. Zhai has recommended could help you, but if you do need to use Glide for some reason, I hope someone here can help yo quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The software GLIDE is not used for RMSD calculation. GLIDE is dedicated to do small ligand/protein docking (rigid/rigid and flexible/rigid).

You can calculate the RMSD by hand, using MAESTRO, CHIMERA and VMD interfaces (all free for academics) among many other software (also free).

Comment: Thank you i thought i hed to use the core tab of glide, but can you explain me how ? because I have to do this but nobody tell me how and the deadline of my thesis is very close :(

Comment: If you are using MAESTRO,  just load both structures you want to determine the RMSD, go to the TASK menu/icon, search for SUPERPOSITION and setup the calculation (you have to put the structures at workspace or select both in the table).

Comment: Many thanks :)
It's the same for the receptor with no non-co-crystallized ligand? beacause i work with 2 receptor one of ths have a non-co-crystallized ligand instead in the otheor one i work in a allosteric binding site with no non-co-crystallized ligand but i have to compare data with a reference ligand known in litterature.

Comment: Sure. The calculation of the RMSD is made in the same way.

Comment: thank you so much.